# How to Make a Framer Motion Slider With Drag and Move on Button Press - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I'm new a new developer and I'm wondering how I can implement moving the translateX on button press without breaking the constraint of the slider on drag. The drag I got, but it's just implementing the buttons is what's confusing me.

[Slider Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7twu.jpg)

The code is a mess because I am going crazy. I just want it to move it's X by some persentage of Pixels everytime the button is press and then the button will disable when at the end of the slider. The exist condition there, I don't need, it's just to show what I tried to do before with the handleRightBtn and handleLeftBtn functions, I don't think I need them because I want it to move by adding the persentage of Pixels to translateX each time, but the other way is plausible. I think you can get the logic of what I'm trying to do but I just can't implement it, can someone please help and show me some guidance

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

// *Design Imports*
import javaScriptLogo from "../../assets/images/Javascript-shield.png";
import HTMLAndCSSLogo from "../../assets/images/pngfind.com-HTML-CSS.png";
import nodeLogo from "../../assets/images/Node.js_logo.svg.png";
import expressLogo from "../../assets/images/express-logo.png";
import ReactLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-react-logo.png";
import reduxLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-Redux.png";
import postgresLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-PostgreSql.png";
import mySqlLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-MySQL.png";
import awsLogo from "../../assets/images/aws.png";
import javaLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-java.png";
import mongoDbLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-mongodb.png";
import gitLogo from "../../assets/images/pngegg-git.png";
import gitHubLogo from "../../assets/images/Github_logo.png";
import dockerLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-Docker.png";
import {
  IoIosArrowDroprightCircle,
  IoIosArrowDropleftCircle,
} from "react-icons/io";
import "./skillsSlider.css";

import { motion, AnimatePresence, useMotionValue } from "framer-motion";

const SkillsSlider = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const carouselRef = useRef(null);
  const [rightBtnClicked, setRightBtnClicked] = useState(false);
  const [leftBtnClicked, setLeftBtnClicked] = useState(false);

  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const [direction, setDirection] = useState(0);
  const [btnClicked, setBtnClicked] = useState(false);

  const [disableLeft, setDisableLeft] = useState(false);
  const [disableRight, setDisableRight] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    carouselRef.current.style.transform =
      "translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(0px)";
    // console.log(carouselRef.current.style.scrollWidth);
    carouselRef !== null &&
      setWidth(
        carouselRef.current.scrollWidth - carouselRef.current.offsetWidth
      );
    console.log(
      carouselRef.current.scrollWidth - carouselRef.current.offsetWidth
    );
  }, []);

  let prev;
  let after;
  // useEffect(() => {
  const handleLeftBtn = () => {
    setLeftBtnClicked(true);
    prev = direction;
    console.log("prev" + prev);
    setDirection(direction - 1);
    after = prev - 1;
    console.log("direc" + after);
  };

  const handleRightBtn = () => {
    setRightBtnClicked(true);
    prev = direction;
    console.log("prev" + prev);
    setDirection(direction + 1);
    after = prev + 1;
    console.log("direc" + after);
  };

  // const x = useMotionValue(0);

  const slide = {
    moveRight: {
        x: "-1453px",
        // opacity: 0,
    },
    center: {
      x: 0,
      // opacity: 0.7,
    },
    moveLeft: {
        x: "1453px",
        // opacity: 0,
    },
    exit: (direction) => {
      return {
        x: after > prev ? "-727px" : "727px",
        // opacity: 0,
      };
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let x = carouselRef.current.style.transform;
    if ((x = "translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(0px)")) {
      setDisableLeft(true);
    } else if ((x = "translateX(-1658px) translateY(0px) translateZ(0px)")) {
      setDisableRight(true);
    } else {
      setDisableLeft(false);
      setDisableRight(false);
    }
  }, [leftBtnClicked, rightBtnClicked]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="btnsContainer">
        <button
          disabled={disableLeft ? true : false}
          className="actionLeftContainer"
          onClick={() => handleLeftBtn()}
        >
          <IoIosArrowDropleftCircle />
        </button>
        <button
          disabled={disableRight ? true : false}
          className="actionRightContainer"
          onClick={() => handleRightBtn()}
        >
          <IoIosArrowDroprightCircle />
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="sliderContainer">
        <AnimatePresence
          initial={false}
          custom={direction}
        >
          <motion.div
            variants={slide}
            animate={
              rightBtnClicked
                ? "moveRight"
                : leftBtnClicked
                ? "moveLeft"
                : undefined
            }
            initial="center"
            exit="exit"
            onAnimationEnd={() => {
              setLeftBtnClicked(false);
              setRightBtnClicked(false);
              console.log(rightBtnClicked);
            }}
            custom={direction}
            key={btnClicked}
            drag="x"
            dragConstraints={{ right: 0, left: -width }}
            className="slider"
            ref={carouselRef}
          >
            <div>
              <img
                loading="lazy"
                src={javaScriptLogo}
                alt="Javascript-shield.png"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img
                loading="lazy"
                src={HTMLAndCSSLogo}
                alt="pngfind.com-HTML-CSS.png"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img loading="lazy" src={nodeLogo} alt="Node.js_logo.svg.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img loading="lazy" src={expressLogo} alt="express-logo.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img
                loading="lazy"
                src={ReactLogo}
                alt="pngwing.com-react-logo.png"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img loading="lazy" src={reduxLogo} alt="pngwing.com-Redux.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img
                loading="lazy"
                src={postgresLogo}
                alt="pngwing.com-PostgreSql.png"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img loading="lazy" src={mySqlLogo} alt="pngwing.com-MySQL.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img loading="lazy" src={awsLogo} alt="aws.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img loading="lazy" src={javaLogo} alt="pngwing.com-java.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img
                loading="lazy"
                src={mongoDbLogo}
                alt="pngwing.com-mongodb.png"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img loading="lazy" src={gitLogo} alt="pngegg-git.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img loading="lazy" src={gitHubLogo} alt="Github_logo.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img
                loading="lazy"
                src={dockerLogo}
                alt="pngwing.com-Docker.png"
              />
            </div>
          </motion.div>
        </AnimatePresence>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SkillsSlider;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, here is how I resolved my problems...! Please, anyone, let me know a better solution if you have any ideas.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

// *Design Imports*
import javaScriptLogo from "../../assets/images/Javascript-shield.png";
import HTMLAndCSSLogo from "../../assets/images/pngfind.com-HTML-CSS.png";
import nodeLogo from "../../assets/images/Node.js_logo.svg.png";
import expressLogo from "../../assets/images/express-logo.png";
import ReactLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-react-logo.png";
import reduxLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-Redux.png";
import postgresLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-PostgreSql.png";
import mySqlLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-MySQL.png";
import awsLogo from "../../assets/images/aws.png";
import javaLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-java.png";
import mongoDbLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-mongodb.png";
import gitLogo from "../../assets/images/pngegg-git.png";
import gitHubLogo from "../../assets/images/Github_logo.png";
import dockerLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-Docker.png";
import figmaLogo from "../../assets/images/pngwing.com-figma.png";
import {
  IoIosArrowDroprightCircle,
  IoIosArrowDropleftCircle,
} from "react-icons/io";
import "./skillsSlider.css";

import { motion, useMotionValue } from "framer-motion";

const SkillsSlider = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const [btnClicked, setBtnClicked] = useState(false);
  const [responsiveSlider, setResponsiveSlider] = useState(false);
  const carouselRef = useRef(null);

  const position = useMotionValue(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    carouselRef !== null &&
      setWidth(
        carouselRef.current.scrollWidth - carouselRef.current.offsetWidth
      );
  }, [responsiveSlider]);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   console.log(position.get(), btnClicked);
  // }, [position, btnClicked]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="btnsContainer">
        <button
          disabled={btnClicked ? true : false}
          className="actionLeftContainer"
          onClick={() => {
            position.getPrevious() >= -941
              ? position.set(0)
              : position.set(position.get() + 941);
            setBtnClicked(true);
            setTimeout(() => {
              setBtnClicked(false);
            }, 1000);
          }}
        >
          <IoIosArrowDropleftCircle />
        </button>
        <button
          disabled={btnClicked ? true : false}
          className="actionRightContainer"
          onClick={() => {
            position.getPrevious() <= -941
              ? position.set(-1882)
              : position.set(position.get() - 941);
            setBtnClicked(true);
            setTimeout(() => {
              setBtnClicked(false);
            }, 1000);
          }}
        >
          <IoIosArrowDroprightCircle />
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="sliderContainer">
        <motion.div
          drag="x"
          dragMomentum={false}
          dragConstraints={{ right: 0, left: -width }}
          // Sets new position of the slider.
          onDragEnd={(e, { offset }) => {
            position.set(position.get() + offset.x);
            // console.log("Drag End", offset);
            // console.log(position.get(), btnClicked);
            setResponsiveSlider(!responsiveSlider);
          }}
          animate={btnClicked && { x: position.get() }}
          transition={
            btnClicked && {
              duration: 1,
              type: "spring",
              stiffness: 45,
            }
          }
          className="slider"
          ref={carouselRef}
        >
          <div>
            <img
              loading="lazy"
              src={javaScriptLogo}
              alt="Javascript-shield.png"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img
              loading="lazy"
              src={HTMLAndCSSLogo}
              alt="pngfind.com-HTML-CSS.png"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img loading="lazy" src={nodeLogo} alt="Node.js_logo.svg.png" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img loading="lazy" src={expressLogo} alt="express-logo.png" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img
              loading="lazy"
              src={ReactLogo}
              alt="pngwing.com-react-logo.png"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img loading="lazy" src={reduxLogo} alt="pngwing.com-Redux.png" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img
              loading="lazy"
              src={postgresLogo}
              alt="pngwing.com-PostgreSql.png"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img loading="lazy" src={mySqlLogo} alt="pngwing.com-MySQL.png" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img loading="lazy" src={awsLogo} alt="aws.png" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img loading="lazy" src={javaLogo} alt="pngwing.com-java.png" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img
              loading="lazy"
              src={mongoDbLogo}
              alt="pngwing.com-mongodb.png"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img loading="lazy" src={gitLogo} alt="pngegg-git.png" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img loading="lazy" src={gitHubLogo} alt="Github_logo.png" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img loading="lazy" src={dockerLogo} alt="pngwing.com-Docker.png" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img loading="lazy" src={figmaLogo} alt="pngwing.com-figma.png" />
          </div>
        </motion.div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SkillsSlider;
```